# Join Results Not Matching Expectation

Tags: t-sql

I feel ridiculous having to ask this but I've been staring at my code now for so long and I can't see what obvious answer I'm missing:

Using AdventureWorks2016 database I have the following query:

```
declare @OrderFrequency table (CustomerID int, OrderYear int, OrderFrequency int)

;with OrderFrequency as
(

Select
      CustomerID,
      datepart(month, OrderDate) OrderMonth,
      datepart(year, OrderDate) OrderYear,
      cast(datepart(month, OrderDate) as nvarchar) +'/'+cast(datepart(year, OrderDate) as nvarchar) MonthYearCode
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by CustomerID, datepart(month, OrderDate), datepart(year, OrderDate)

)
insert into @OrderFrequency
Select CustomerID, OrderYear, count(distinct MonthYearCode) OrderFrequency
from OrderFrequency
group by CustomerID, OrderYear
order by CustomerID, OrderYear


declare @CTETable table (CustomerID int, OrderTotal float, OrderMonth int, OrderYear int)
;with CTE as
(
Select
      CustomerID,
      sum(TotalDue) OrderTotal,
      datepart(month, OrderDate) OrderMonth,
      datepart(year, OrderDate) OrderYear
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by CustomerID, datepart(month, OrderDate), datepart(year, OrderDate)

)
insert into @CTETable
select * from CTE

Select CTET.*
from @CTETable CTET
left outer join @OrderFrequency Ord on Ord.CustomerID = CTET.CustomerID
order by CTET.CustomerID, CTET.OrderYear
```

My final select statement is returning all from CTET, with extra rows returned from the join on @OrderFrequency.

Should my specification of CTET.* return ONLY CTET?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. You get the columns from `CTET`, sure, but you one row for each successful join... Shove in a `DISTINCT` and you'll see a difference.

Comment: Afraid I don't follow, either. `CTET.* ` determines which _columns_ come back. Your `JOIN` determines which _rows_ come back. Where is your discrepancy?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not sure why I was having such trouble wrapping my head around this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Ord can have multiple rows per CustomerID, you will get more rows back from your join than CTET has. That is your row set, no matter how which columns you decide to show. Whether you select CTET.* or select Ord.*, your row count will remain the same.

If you want to reduce that set to eliminate the duped data in CTET columns as a result of the left join, you can select distinct CTET.* instead.

What is your goal with that join?

Comment: Thanks Leia. My brain just stopped working. I've got it back online now and functioning correctly.